# Why is it that when I drop a field in table it says `#1050 - Table already exist`

Tags: mysql

I want to drop some fields of a table but it returns an error. 
the query is..

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_incoming_bub` DROP `approved_date`, DROP `approved_by`, DROP `incoming_date`, DROP `incoming_by`, DROP `obligate_date`, DROP `obligate_by`, DROP `journal_date`, DROP `journal_by`, DROP `ana_date`, DROP `ana_by`;
```

and the error is.. `#1050 - Table 'ncddp/#sql-ib176' already exists`

Here is the screenshots..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this](https://twindb.com/resolving-error-1050-42s01-at-line-1-table-sakilasql-ib712-already-exists/) post by [Aleksandr Kuzminsky](https://twindb.com/author/akuzminsky/) who not only provides a solution, but also (and maybe more importantly) an explanation of what's going on. Kuzminsky is a former [Percona](http://www.percona.com/) employee (Percona is a big hitter in the MySQL ecosphere) and a contributor to open source MySQL projects on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/undrop-for-innodb).

Basically, what happens is this

When you run an alter table, MySQL creates a temporary table with the new structure. The name of the new table is (something like) #sql-ib712.

It appears that MySQL doesn't choose very random names for these temporary tables. The problem arises when there's a crash in the middle of the ALTER TABLE process and the dictionary ends up with an orphaned table. Which wouldn't be a problem, except that MySQL (due to the non-random nature of temp table naming) has a good chance of giving the same name to a subsequent temporary table.

Obviously, Kuzminsky goes into a bit more detail, and provides a script to help fix your database.

Comment: You might try moving `#sql-ib176.*` out of the directory while mysqld is shutdown.  That's a lot simpler, and might work.

Comment: @RickJames The problem not with a file on the file system, but with a record in the dictionary. So, removing the file will not help.

Comment: @akuzminsky - `#sql-ib176.*` is probably a temp table that wasn't deleted after a crash.

Comment: Nope. `#1050 - Table 'ncddp/#sql-ib176' already exists` comes from InnoDB that can't create a record in `SYS_TABLES` because `NAME` is a primary key. Note `ncddp/#sql-ib176` - it's a value of `NAME`. Even if you delete the file it won't delete the record from `SYS_TABLES`.